# Shell Script CURL JSON value to variable

Tags: json, macos, shell, curl

I was wondering how to parse the CURL JSON output from the server into variables.

Currently, I have -

```
curl -X POST -H "Content: agent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://www.toontownrewritten.com/api/login?format=json -d username="$USERNAME" -d password="$PASSWORD" | python -m json.tool
```

But it only outputs the JSON from the server and then have it parsed, like so:

```
{
    "eta": "0",
    "position": "0",
    "queueToken": "6bee9e85-343f-41c7-a4d3-156f901da615",
    "success": "delayed"
}
```

But how do I put - for example the success value above returned from the server into a variable $SUCCESS and have the value as delayed & have queueToken as a variable $queueToken and 6bee9e85-343f-41c7-a4d3-156f901da615 as a value?

Then when I use-

```
echo "$SUCCESS"
```

it shows this as the output -

```
delayed
```

And when I use

```
echo "$queueToken"
```

and the output as

```
6bee9e85-343f-41c7-a4d3-156f901da615
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already try something? Please share your trys!

Comment: I didnt really try anything, for now, I just manually have echo to ask the user questions of what is the output of the JSON and have user manually type in it and have it stored inside the variable with "read SUCCESS" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use perl module on command line:

1st, ensure they is installed, under debian based, you could

```
sudo apt-get install libjson-xs-perl
```

But for other OS, you could install perl modules via [CPAN (the *Comprehensive Perl Archive Network*)](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html):

```
cpan App::cpanminus
cpan JSON::XS
```

Note: You may have to run this with superuser privileges.

then:

```
curlopts=(-X POST -H
    "Content: apent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    -d username="$USERNAME" -d password="$PASSWORD")
curlurl=https://www.toontownrewritten.com/api/login?format=json

. <(
    perl -MJSON::XS -e '
        $/=undef;my $a=JSON::XS::decode_json <> ;
        printf "declare -A Json=\047(%s)\047\n", join " ",map {
            "[".$_."]=\"".$a->{$_}."\""
        } qw|queueToken success eta position|;
    ' < <(
        curl "${curlopts[@]}" $curlurl
    )
)
```

The line `qw|...|` let you precise which variables you want to be driven... This could be replaced by `keys $a`, but could have to be debugged as some characters is forbiden is *associative arrays* values names.

```
echo ${Json[queueToken]}
6bee9e85-343f-41c7-a4d3-156f901da615

echo ${Json[eta]}
0
```

Comment: This doesnt work as I had hoped... I cant seem to use `echo ${Json[queueToken]}` when I used the code.

Comment: @JeremyZh answer edited: added some double quotes and tested with real url (my 1st test used some json of mine)...

Comment: but as I don't have an account, I could only: `echo ${!Json[@]}` give: `banner success` and `echo ${Json[success]}` print `false`

Comment: I am on a mac intel environment, that use shell scripting. So I do not know where I can install JSON::XS perl libs... Also after using the code along with `echo ${Json[queueToken]}`, it outputs nothing, i suppose I need to install some dependencies so it works. Where/how can I install JSON::XS perl libs? `sudo apt-get install libjson-xs-perl` doesnt work on mac. You can always make a disposable account in [https://www.toontownrewritten.com/register](https://www.toontownrewritten.com/register).

Comment: You may install perl modules from [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).

Comment: Alright, I installed cpanminus and XS using above commands, but when I used `echo ${Json[queueToken]}` and it shows up nothing. I had `set -x` enabled, so http://pastebin.com/gGdbHJQN this is the log output. But it doesnt show my  `echo ${Json[queueToken]}` commands.

Comment: 1st, look about `Json` variable with: `declare -p Json`. 2st try `curl` command itself, to ensure they return json datas: whipe all parenthesis and run `curl "${curlopts[@]}" $curlurl`. If they work, run perl alone, without `. <(` and latest `)` to see perl output: `perl -MJSON::XS -e '...' < <(curl "${curlopts[@]}" $curlurl )` this could render something like: `declare -A Json='(...)'` ... Of course, `$USERNAME` and `$PASSWORD` have to be set before `curlopts=(-X...)`!

Answer (score 3):

Find and install `jq` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). `jq` is a JSON parser. JSON is not reliably parsed by line-oriented tools like `sed` because, like XML, JSON is not a line-oriented data format.

In terms of your question:

```
source <(
    curl -X POST -H "$content_type" "$url" -d username="$USERNAME" -d password="$PASSWORD" | 
    jq -r '. as $h | keys | map(. + "=\"" + $h[.] + "\"") | .[]'
)
```

The `jq` syntax is a bit weird, I'm still working on it. It's basically a series of filters, each pipe taking the previous input and transforming it. In this case, the end result is some lines that look like `variable="value"`

This answer uses bash's "process substitution" to take the results of the `jq` command, treat it like a file, and `source` it into the current shell. The variables will then be available to use.

Comment: Tried it, but How do I call the variables? Like, `echo "$queueToken"`?

Comment: I tried `source <(
curl -X POST -H "Content: apent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://www.toontownrewritten.com/api/login?format=json -d username="$USERNAME" -d password="$PASSWORD" | jq -r '. as $h | keys | map(. + "=\"" + $h[.] + "\"") | .[]' | jq -r '.queueToken as $queueToken'
)

echo "$queueToken"`, but I never seem to make this work.

Comment: you need to remove the pipe to the 2nd `jq` command: it's eating the output of the first `jq`, so the `source` doesn't have any effect. The `$queueToken` in that jq command is a jq variable, not a shell variable. Do `set -x` and then run the command I showed.

Comment: How do I pipe the jq variables to shell then?

Comment: You don't. The `<(,,,)` process substitution syntax executes the command and holds the output in something the shell can handle like a file. Then, the `source` command evaluates the contents of that "file" in your current shell. It is the `source` command that actually creates the variables given the `jq` output.

Comment: How do I use/call the variable like in shell's echo or something similar?

Comment: Shell variables are created witth the same as the JSON object keys

Comment: How can I use it, im very new to this. sorry.

Comment: So currently I have `source <(
curl -X POST -H "Content: apent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://www.toontownrewritten.com/api/login?format=json -d username="$USERNAME" -d password="$PASSWORD" | jq -r '. as $h | keys | map(. + "=\"" + $h[.] + "\"") | .[]'
)` and next like as `echo $queueToken`, but that variable is empty. How do I call the json output from curl http post, for example, queueToken, as form as a variable so I can use it like echo commands, etc?

Comment: Now you have to learn how to debug shell scripts. First, run the `curl | jq` commands alone. What is the output?

Comment: `$ curl | jq
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.4]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]

For a description of the command line options and
how to write jq filters (and why you might want to)
see the jq manpage, or the online documentation at
http://stedolan.github.com/jq`  - That is the output of `curl | jq`

Comment: ok, I understand you're new at this, but you're not thinking at all about what I'm asking you to run. Why would I ask you to run curl and jq with no parameters?

Comment: you asked me to "run the curl | jq commands alone"......? Im so sorry to waste your time at this, but I am working on developing a simple command line launcher, but I hit my head when I cant make it auto read the curl output jsons.

Comment: Could we [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77470/discussion-between-jeremyzh-and-glenn-jackman)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of [Extract a JSON value from a BASH script](https://gist.github.com/cjus/1047794)

```
#!/bin/bash
function jsonval {
    temp=`echo $json | sed 's/\\\\\//\//g' | sed 's/[{}]//g' | awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | sed 's/\"\:\"/\|/g' | sed 's/[\,]/ /g' | sed 's/\"//g' | grep -w $prop`
    echo ${temp##*|}
}

json=`curl -s -X GET http://twitter.com/users/show/$1.json`
prop='profile_image_url'
picurl=`jsonval`

`curl -s -X GET $picurl -o $1.png`
```

> A bash script which demonstrates parsing a JSON string to extract a
>   property value. The script contains a jsonval function which operates
>   on two variables, json and prop. When the script is passed the name of
>   a twitter user it attempts to download the user's profile picture.

Comment: I do not know how to use this in terms of my script, mind demonstrating how it works and how I use it? Thanks!